# How to ignore zooming on image view Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, swift3, drawimage

I am new to iOS and now developing an application like indoor navigation system , the view contains scroll view and it contains imageView holding my map , when detest beacon near i get its coordinates(x, y) and draw a dot blue over the image successfully , but if i zoom in or out the drawing function draw in wrong places .

**Question:** How to ignore the zoom status while drawing the point?

**My code:**

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.5
```

**The drawing code is:**

```
extension UIImageView {

func addDashedLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
    print("Make sure of startr point")
    print(start)
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: start)
    linePath.addLine(to: end)
    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    line.lineWidth = 3
    line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    line.lineDashPattern = [1, 1]
    line.zPosition = 2
    self.layer.addSublayer(line)
    }
  }
```

**And the use of it any my code like:**

```
let start = CGPoint(x: oldX, y: oldY)
            let end = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
            print("old ponit is \(start)")
            self.mapView.addDashedLine(fromPoint: start, toPoint: end)
```

**Moving code is:**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            self.dotBlue.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.defaults.set(CGFloat(x), forKey: "currentLocationX")
            self.defaults.set(CGFloat(y), forKey: "currentLocationY")
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                print("Animation Ended!")
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isZoomEnabled` property of the `MKMapView`.

So something like

```
self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = false
let start = CGPoint(x: oldX, y: oldY)
let end = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
print("old point is \(start)")
self.mapView.addDashedLine(fromPoint: start, toPoint: end)
self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
```

Just make sure that whatever you disable gets re-enabled as soon as the drawing is done.

Comment: Thanks @Samantha but it does not work , i want to move small over imageView it is on a large imageView on a scrollView

Comment: Ah, ok...I misunderstood, sorry. The scrollView is the thing that is zooming? Have you tried temporarily setting `scrollView`'s `maximumZoomScale` to 1.0, and then setting it back when the drawing is finished?

Comment: yes but still no result , i added the animation code of moving the small imageView up

Comment: So you want to disable zoom while adding the dashed line and while performing the animations? What is the order of things happening here?

Comment: I solved adding line by redraw the image with new line... the problem is when app detect beacon must move succecfully the point to the right place even scrollview is zoomed in or out